# For a linear mapping to be a bijection, is it necessary to include the dimension of the domain and co-domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

Suppose I have an operator $U$ which maps elements from $\mathcal{O}$ to  $\mathcal{D}$. To show that it is bijective, $U$ must be:
1)surjective (onto)
2)injective (one-to-one)

However, in some places, I have seen as an additional requirement that the dimension of $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ must be equal:
3)$\mathcal{O}_d$ =  $\mathcal{D}_d$

Is 3) necessary to include, or do all mappings that satisfy 1) and 2) automatically satisfy 3)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Condition 3 is *necessary*, but not sufficient: a linear map between two spaces of different dimensions *cannot* be bijective. Since often one knows the dimensions ahead of time, this is an easier check than checking whether the function is injective and surjective. If the dimensions are different, then there is no need to check injectivity or surjectivity, because if the dimensions are different then you know for sure it is not bijective.

In addition, for finite dimensions, when $\dim(\mathcal{O})=\dim(\mathcal{D})$, then the following are equivalent for linear maps: $U$ is injective; $U$ is surjective; $U$ is bijective. So if you have (3) then it suffices to have (1) **or** (2) (rather than both) to establish bijectivity.

It is true that any bijective *linear* map from $\mathcal{O}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ will satisfy (3), though.

Comment: Great answer. Question about the last line of your answer: is the word "linear" necessary? Meaning, is there a nonlinear map which satisfies (1),(2), but not (3)?

Comment: @Idieh Yes; for example there are bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is not linear); such a bijection satisfies (1) and (2), but definitely not (3).

Comment: @Idieh Note that the OP's question and this answer are using the word "necessary" with a slightly different meaning. Condition 3 is "necessary" in the sense that if condition 3 is false, then the map is not a bijection; but it is not necessary to explicitly talk about condition 3 in order to write a valid proof that the map is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to prove that a function $U : \mathcal O \to \mathcal D$ is a bijection.

Any of the following proofs is valid:

- Prove that $U$ is an injection and that $U$ is a surjection.
- Prove that $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal D$ are vector spaces, that $U$ is a linear map, that $U$ is **injective**, and that $\dim \mathcal O \geq \dim \mathcal D$.
- Prove that $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal D$ are vector spaces, that $U$ is a linear map, that $U$ is **surjective**, and that $\dim \mathcal O \leq \dim \mathcal D$.

Notice how if you know that the dimensions are equal, then you don't need to prove both injectivity and surjectivity: just prove one, and the other follows automatically.

Additionally, the following is a valid proof that $U$ is ***not*** a bijection:

- Prove that $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal D$ are vector spaces, that $U$ is a linear map, and that $\dim \mathcal O \neq \dim \mathcal D$.

All in all, testing whether the dimensions are equal or not seems very useful, even if it's not required to write a valid proof.